# How to add or subtract a "like" based on original value, only one time?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make whenever I click "like", the program adds 1 to the value. Also, if I click "unlike" it subtracts 1 from the original value. But only one time.

As I can like one time and I can dislike one time ... (NOTE IF I UNLIKED AN ALREADY LIKED VALUE .. it subtracts From the original VALUE)

```js
var checker = true;
$(".like").click(function() {
  if (checker) {
    var value = $(this).siblings(".total").text();
    var integer = parseInt(value)
    y = integer + 1;
    var value = $(this).siblings(".total").text(y);
    checker = false;
  }
});
$(".unlike").click(function() {
  if (checker) {
    var value = $(this).siblings(".total").text();
    var integer = parseInt(value)
    y = integer - 1;
    var value = $(this).siblings(".total").text(y);
    checker = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=p arent>
  <button class="like">LIKE!</button>
  <p class="total">5</p>
  <button class="unlike">UNLIKE</button>
</div>
<div class=parent>
  <button class="like">LIKE!</button>
  <p class="total">12</p>
  <button class="unlike">UNLIKE</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Jakupov/xpvt214o/400688/).

Basic solution is to save state of every `.like` or `.unlike` in corresponding block. I have used `.parent`'s `data`.

If you want it to be likeable after like and dislike or vice versa, you should have to change opposite status to false, like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Jakupov/xpvt214o/400702/).

Answer (score 0):

Try it :)

```js
$(document).on('click', '.like', function() {
  var attr = $(this).parent('.parent').attr('checked');
  if (!(typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false)) {
    var value = $(this).siblings('.total').text();
    var interger = parseInt(value);
    ++interger;
    $(this).siblings('.total').text(interger);
    $(this).parent('.parent').attr('checked', 'checked');
  }
});
$(document).on('click', '.unlike', function() {
  var attr = $(this).parent('.parent').attr('checked');
  if (!(typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false)) {
    var value = $(this).siblings('.total').text();
    var interger = parseInt(value);
    --interger;
    $(this).siblings('.total').text(interger);
    $(this).parent('.parent').attr('checked', 'checked');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=parent>
  <button class="like">LIKE!</button> <button class="unlike">UNLIKE</button>
  <p class="total">5</p>
</div>
<div class=parent>
  <button class="like">LIKE!</button> <button class="unlike">UNLIKE</button>
  <p class="total">12</p>
</div>
```

Comment: If you do not like the button, the button will be activated

Comment: NICE BUT when i unlike an already liked value it does not subtract from this value

Comment: the problem is i want it to add +1 even  if you unliked the button but this must be done one time .. and vice versa and this was my original question

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting property to respective `.total` field.

```js
var checker = true;
$(".like").click(function() {
  if ($(this).siblings(".total").prop("likeValue") == 1)
    return;
  var value = $(this).siblings(".total").text();
  var integer = parseInt(value);

  if ($(this).siblings(".total").prop("likeValue") == -1)
    y = integer + 2;
  else
    y = integer + 1; 

  var value = $(this).siblings(".total").text(y);
  $(this).siblings(".total").prop("likeValue", 1);
});
$(".unlike").click(function() {
  if ($(this).siblings(".total").prop("likeValue") == -1)
    return;
  var value = $(this).siblings(".total").text();
  var integer = parseInt(value)
  if ($(this).siblings(".total").prop("likeValue") == 1)
    y = integer - 2;
  else
    y = integer - 1;      
  var value = $(this).siblings(".total").text(y);
  $(this).siblings(".total").prop("likeValue", -1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=p arent>
  <button class="like">LIKE!</button>
  <p class="total">5</p>
  <button class="unlike">UNLIKE</button>
</div>
<div class=parent>
  <button class="like">LIKE!</button>
  <p class="total">12</p>
  <button class="unlike">UNLIKE</button>
</div>
```